# Angular js - require js file from view using lazy load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading, require

How can i include multiple js files in lazy load, so when page finished to load and angular has been executed?

I tryed with a custom directive and the code looks like:
//html

```
<ng-lazy-load data-type="script" data-src='["file.js"]'></ng-lazy-load>
```

//directive

```
.directive('ngLazyLoad', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl:'views/modules/module_lazy_load.html',
      scope:true,
      link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
        if(attr.type === 'script'){
          $scope.src = JSON.parse(attr.src);
        }

      }
    };
  }]);
```

//directive view

```
<script ng-if="src" ng-repeat="path in src" src="{{path}}"></script>
```

//file.js to be included in lazy load

```
alert('daf***');
```

Comment: the answer is no. if its in a template wont even run it.

Comment: @mpm so no way to conditionally call js files from template right?

Comment: there is always a way it is just javascript after all.the question is ,does it make sense to do that. But you can still append a script to the body element in pure javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so, as script is loaded before angular can take over.

How about a directive that can check your stuff and then you can $document.write the script to the index.html?

Have the controller in charge of the scope variable be injected into the directive, then it can write to the html conditionally.

Comment: we had some dirty nasty code that did this in a disgusting JS file, but if its included in a directive then why not - as its localized to one area and scope.

Comment: sure i agree just waiting for morep eople to answer or comment so that we can have more feedbacks about it

Comment: later i'll try with a directive cause i like this approach, if it works and no best alternatives i'll tell you thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Nay. It's a temporally inconsistent idea: A script tag is executed when it's encountered while parsing the DOM. What would it even mean to "switch it off" later? It will have already been executed by then.

Comment: if you create a new DOM element when page is ready, i guess it get parsed and executed also if its <script> tag nope? i don't need to switch off just to switch it on when i want ( if possible )